# lexical databases of semantic relations between words- computer science taxonomies

Tags: ontology, similarity, semantics, taxonomy

What are the lexical databases of semantic relations between words for the computer science taxonomies (e.g. artificial intelligence, machine learning, sensor networks, Computer vision, etc) other than WordNet?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking for databases of relations between *words* such as "reinforcement" or "learning" or between entire concepts or terms (e.g. "hierarchical reiinforcement learning")? These questions may have different answers. If the latter, did you already consider general resources like Wikidata and DBpedia, as well as the Computer Science Ontology (http://cso.kmi.open.ac.uk/home)?

Comment: @Chris Mungall, thank you, I want to find the semantic similarities between entire concepts or terms of the computer science domain such as machine learning, artificial intelligence, machine learning, sensor networks, sensors, Computer vision,  reinforcement learning,  etc)